# Use uniform buffer of uvec3[]

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have the following uniform buffer:

```
uniform EDGE_ID_TO_START_POS{
    uint[12*3] pos;
} edgeIdToStartPos;
```

Writing to this buffer works perfectly fine:

```
#define EDGE_ID_TO_START_POS_SIZE (12*3)
    const uint32_t edgeIdToStartPos_constBuffer[EDGE_ID_TO_START_POS_SIZE] = {
        /* 0*/ 0, 0, 0, /* 1*/ 0, 1, 0, /* 2*/ 1, 0, 0, /* 3*/ 0, 0, 0,
        /* 4*/ 0, 0, 1, /* 5*/ 0, 1, 1, /* 6*/ 1, 0, 1, /* 7*/ 0, 0, 1,
        /* 8*/ 0, 0, 0, /* 9*/ 0, 1, 0, /*10*/ 1, 1, 0, /*11*/ 1, 0, 0
    };
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo);
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, EDGE_ID_TO_START_POS_SIZE * sizeof(uint32_t), edgeIdToStartPos_constBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
```

Now I want to change the uniform buffer to the following structure:

```
uniform EDGE_ID_TO_START_POS{
    uvec3[12] pos;
} edgeIdToStartPos;
```

This structure makes more sense and is easier to use. And it should have the same memory layout than the previous version (?).
However, when reading from this struct, only the vectors 0..3 contain data. All `uvec`s with an index of 4 or higher contain zeros.

Why does this happen and how can I initialise such a uniform buffer correctly?
(C/C++, glew, glfw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `uvec3` has an alignment of 16 bytes, so you must add padding.  See OpenGL 4.5 spec, section 7.6.22:

> If the member is a three-component vector with components consuming *N* basic machine units, the base alignment is 4*N*.

Here is how it would look:

```
static const int EDGE_ID_TO_START_POS_SIZE = 12 * 4;
const uint32_t edgeIdToStartPos_constBuffer[EDGE_ID_TO_START_POS_SIZE] = {
    /* 0*/ 0, 0, 0, 0, /* 1*/ 0, 1, 0, 0, /* 2*/ 1, 0, 0, 0, /* 3*/ 0, 0, 0, 0,
    /* 4*/ 0, 0, 1, 0, /* 5*/ 0, 1, 1, 0, /* 6*/ 1, 0, 1, 0, /* 7*/ 0, 0, 1, 0,
    /* 8*/ 0, 0, 0, 0, /* 9*/ 0, 1, 0, 0, /*10*/ 1, 1, 0, 0, /*11*/ 1, 0, 0, 0,
};
```

Comment: This is one reason you should never used vec3's of any kind in uniform/storage blocks.

Comment: Would it be valid to write it this way (seems to work): `#define EDGE_ID_TO_DIRECTION_SIZE (12*3)
 const GLuvec3  edgeIdToDirection_constBuffer[12] = {
  /* 0*/ GLuvec3{ 0, 1, 0 }, /* 1*/ GLuvec3{ 1, 0, 0 }, ...
 };`  With struct `GLuvec3{GLuint x, y, z;};`

Comment: @NicolBolas: I'm not convinced that `vec3` is wrong as long as you are aware of the padding... if you use `vec4` you might wonder what the fourth component is supposed to be used for, and then you would have to remember that it's really just a `vec3`.

Comment: @maja: There's no such type as a `GLuvec3`, last time I checked.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I made my own struct containing 3 GLuint values, which apprently results in the same padding.

Comment: @maja: In C or C++, a struct with three `GLuint` values should have no padding.  The padding rules for C, C++, and OpenGL are all different (yes, C and C++ are different).